# notes style field in xpages

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

Is there any possibility to make an `editbox` in xpages that looks like an `editable field - notes style` from Lotus Notes? Or to be able to display the field value in more lines, if it necessary ?

I tried adding `Auto` for the `editbox`, but it no works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rows and cols properties allow you to change the size. You can also use Dojo Simple Text Area or Dojo Text Area controls from Ext Lib. The latter auto-expands depending on the content, so rows and cols are not applicable (see the part in XPages Extension Library book on that).

If you're talking about the field handles round the top left and bottom right of a field, I don't think web development supports partial borders. It will be a generic CSS web development solution you require, rather than anything specific to XPages.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of late but here's what I came up with:

https://codepen.io/gcoxdev/pen/MmdrYz

```
<div class="notes-field">
    <div class="notes-editable contenteditable="true"></div>
    <textarea name="test"></textarea>
</div>
```

Of course, you'll have to convert that to xpages markup.
Essentially I'm creating a content-editable div with unicode characters for the handles then updating the underlying textarea with javascript.

You can read my article about it here:

http://gcoxdev.com/xpages-notes-style-field

Hope that helps!